# Sphinx doesn't process python classes

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

Gooday,
I'm having trouble at autogenerating python documentation.
My project layout is the following:

project_folder

- package

  - module1.py
  - module2.py
- doc

  - make.bat
  - build
  - source

    - index.rst
    - package.rst
    - modules.rst
    - conf.py

inside module1.py and module2.py there are some classes (with docstrings). I've added in conf.py the following line:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../package'))
```

both modules.rst and package.rst have been generating by calling:

```
sphinx-apidoc -o doc/source package/
```

inside the  folder. Finally, I've added "modules" inside the index.rst file as displayed below (not the whole index.rst, but it was generated by sphinx-quickstart):

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   modules
```

I have several issues:

1) when I call sphinx-autodoc from doc/ directory the documentation isn't generated. In order to correctly generate the documentaiton, I have to replace package.module1 with module1 inside package.rst:

```
#before
.. automodule:: package.module1
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
#after
.. automodule:: module1
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

How can I automatically perform this operation? Or is my setup faulty?

2) If module1.py contains only a bunch of defs, the documentation is generated correctly. However, if I put only a class inside it, the documentation isn't generated at all (note that package.rst file remains unchanged even after running a second time a sphinx-apidoc). What can I do to display class documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after viewing sphinx logs (my bad for not posting them out) I realized the answer for the first issue: if you want to use the sphinx-apidoc output you have to add in conf.py the parent of "Package" package, not package itself

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../')) #documentation is detected
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../package')) #documentation isn't detected
```

In this way python import the  folder in PYTHONPATH, thereby solving the "Package.module1"/"Package.module2" path.
As for the issue #2, I realized (again, my bad) sphinx generated documentation only for public members and my class had only dunder methods (like __ init__). If you want to document those methods (like me), be sure to add in the .rst files :special-members: under the module loaded:

```
.. automodule:: Package.module2
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
    :private-members: # if you want to document __x attributes
    :special-members: # if you want to document __xxx__ dunder methods
```